# Run the same function after it's done forever

Tags: node.js, infinite-loop

I have a loop and a function `tick`. I want to run `tick` every time the SQL response says there is an item in queue, if not then wait 1 sec and try again. If we decide do run `tick` then we wait for it to be done and then we check again in the database after a new item in queue.

The problem here is that `myLoop()` does not wait for `tick()` to be done. I tried to add a callback function but that did not help.

So now to my question, how do you make a loop like this and make it run forever?

My tick function works as it should if I run it like `tick(id-number)` outside of the `myLoop` function. The code also works if I do something like this

```
tick(id-number1, function(result) {
      tick(id-number2, function(result) {
             tick(id-number3, function(result) {

             });
      });
});
```

But then I can't run it forever.

```
function myLoop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //get the first item in queue
        var query = "SELECT id FROM queue where place='" + name + "' order by placeinqueue ASC limit 1";
        console.log(query);
        sendQueryToDatabase(query, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            //if we have a item in queue, run tick and when finished restart the loop
            if (result.length > 0) {
                tick(result[0].id, function(result) {
                    if (result) {
                        myLoop();
                    }
                });
            }
            //else restart the loop and wait 1 sec
            else {
                myLoop();
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you also added your `tick` function's code. Is `tick` function working? Do you see the result (through console.log)?

Comment: Why don't you use [`async.forever`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#forever-fn-errback)?

Answer (score 0):

Try async module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#forever.

forever(fn, errback)
Calls the asynchronous function fn with a callback parameter that allows it to call itself again, in series, indefinitely.